# 403 Forbidden when using access token from OAuth2ServiceAccount - Error Site must be added to your account and verified

Tags: google-oauth, google-authentication, google-authenticator

403 Forbidden when using access token from OAuth2ServiceAccount
My request is inserting sitemap.xml to webmaster tool
here the response from google

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Content-length: 48
X-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
X-content-type-options: nosniff
X-google-cache-control: remote-fetch
-content-encoding: gzip
Server: GSE
Reason: Forbidden
Via: HTTP/1.1 GWA
Cache-control: private, max-age=0
Date: Tue, 29 Jan 2013 11:03:08 GMT
X-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Expires: Tue, 29 Jan 2013 11:03:08 GMT
Site must be added to your account and verified.
```

Comment: What API are you trying to use? What is your access token scoped for?

Comment: Hi William,
webmaster tool API  
scope = https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/feeds/